# JWT Format on ASP.NET Web API 2.2 .NET 4.6.1

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am trying to use JWT format on a Web API 2.2 project. I have followed the steps on [this article - 'Implement OAuth JSON Web Tokens Authentication in ASP.NET Web API and Identity 2.1"](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/)

I downloaded the source code from [AspNetIdentity.WebApi](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AspNetIdentity.WebApi)

But I am using .NET 4.6.1, so my NuGet Package Manager shows an update for package "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" from version 4.0 to 5.0, after I update this package, my project won't compile because I get a "Missing reference error" on my CustomJwtFormat class:

This is the code for my CustomJwtFormat class:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace AspNetIdentity.WebApi.Providers
{
    public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
    {
        private readonly string _issuer = string.Empty;

        public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer) {_issuer = issuer;}

        public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {throw new ArgumentNullException("data");}

            string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];

            string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"];

            var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);

            var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);

            var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;

            var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

            return jwt;
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if anyone has had any luck using this approach on 4.6.1 having all their NuGet packages updated.